# Why the difference between tools executed from ArcGIS toolbox and tools executed from Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, nodata

While using the Copy Raster tool from data management toolbox, I get the following different behaviors when using it from ArcGIS PRO and when using it as Python script. The script behind the two approaches is exactly the same and was achieved by running the tool (from the toolbox) once, and downloading the script locally from History – Save as Python script option. So, using copy raster from the ArcGIS toolbox produces a result (delete.tif) with the following properties:

[image: Results from ArcGIS toolbox]

This is the desired behavior. Saving this process as python script and checking it shows the following code:

```
import arcpy
##arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"@\Data Management Tools.tbx")
with arcpy.EnvManager(compression="'LZW' 75", tileSize="256 256", pyramid="PYRAMIDS 10 NEAREST NONE 75 NO_SKIP NO_SIPS", nodata="NONE"):
    arcpy.management.CopyRaster(
        in_raster=r"R:\ArcGIS\scripttest\originals\20231031_minusma_1m5_spot6_Kidal_RFS-1-11348881257\IMG_SPOT6_PMS_202310311010370_ORT_6841406101_R1C1.JP2",
        out_rasterdataset=r"R:\ArcGIS\scripttest\delete2.tif",
        config_keyword="",
        background_value=None,
        nodata_value="",
        onebit_to_eightbit="NONE",
        colormap_to_RGB="NONE",
        pixel_type="8_BIT_UNSIGNED",
        scale_pixel_value="ScalePixelValue",
        RGB_to_Colormap="NONE",
        format="TIFF",
        transform="NONE",
        process_as_multidimensional="CURRENT_SLICE",
        build_multidimensional_transpose="NO_TRANSPOSE"
    )
```

Executing this exact script (except the arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"@\Data Management Tools.tbx") statement which I believe is not needed) from any code editor produces the following result (delete2.tif) with the following properties:

[image: Results directly from Python]

Do you know why the different results regarding the NoData values? Everything else seems to be kept the same.

Comment: It is not possible for 8-bit unsigned data to store 65535 (max is 255), so these are functionally equivalent.

Comment: I know that the value of 65535 will not show anywhere but our data goes through some Quality Control and this field has to be empty.